# Compiling C++ program using MS Visual Studio 2010 as to not depend on any external code or redistributables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, compilation

I want my exe to be runnable without depending on any redistributable packages but when I set 
"Use of MFC" to "Use MFC in a Static Library" in the Project > Properties menu, I get errors such as this one: 
 - Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_GetWindowTextW@12 referenced in function _wmain
So basically I get unresolved external symbol for the  functions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Project->Properties->Linker->Command Line type user32.lib

Answer (score 2):

Under the linker settings for your project, make sure you've included the default libraries under "Additional Dependencies".

This is usually:

```
kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

Also, make sure have not set "Ignore All Default Libraries".

Comment: It seems like this doesn't help. When I compile in release mode I get the following error: MSB6006: "mt.exe" exited with code 31.

Comment: MT.EXE is the Manifest Tool.  Google "Manifest Tool error 31" for solutions to this issue.